# c# take new data from db/ live update

Tags: c#, java, ajax, database, partial-page-refresh

this is webapp/ it must retrieve all "new" data from DB. ex> there was added new data in DB/ so this WebApp must show this data immediately without refreshing all page/ it's kind of live update! :)

Answer (score 1):

Since Web App can only request the data from server and get the response.
You can use javascript setInterval() method to request your db every few seconds  using ajax .
If there is new data in db you get that data in response of ajax request in append that data on your DOM.. FOR Ex.

```
 setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax(
          // your request code.
         success: function(){
              if(data){//append DOM}
             }
            )
 }
```